# Does HAVING operate on a per-row or per-group basis?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Does the HAVING clause within SQL operate on a per-row or per-group basis?

That is, does it remove individual rows that don't meet the constraint specified?

Or does it only ever remove entire groups that don't meet the constraint specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HAVING` filters the results *after* the `GROUP BY`.  Hence, it filters one row per group.

The `HAVING` can have aggregation expressions that are not in the `SELECT`.  These are implicitly included in the aggregation, although they are not in the result set.

MySQL extends the `HAVING` clause.  When there is no aggregation, then it behaves like a `WHERE`, except it allows column aliases.

MySQL also extends the `GROUP BY` to include unaggregated columns.  You can think of these as being an aggregation function `ANY()` that returns a value for that expression from any row in the group.

Comment: @SalmanA - One implicit group ***per row*** maybe...  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eF4nGrUxGNLJUGfNt16Fhc/0

Comment: "HAVING filters the results after the GROUP BY. Hence, it filters one row per group."

Does this mean that each of the groups produced by "GROUP BY" exist as a single aggregated row, rather than a set of individual, related rows?

Comment: For example, we use a GROUP BY clause that creates three groups. Does this mean we have three sets of individual, related rows, or just three rows, where each row is an aggrated representation of the rows that are in that "group"?

Comment: @J.Doe . . . Yes.  The aggregation operator takes a group of rows (which could be a single row) and produces one row.  This is the row that is handled by the `having`.

Comment: @MatBailie my bad. I have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY activated which disables non-standard behavior. With standard behavior, HAVING without GROUP BY creates one implicit group (and you can only use MIN/MAX/COUNT/etc functions there).